# How to identify web crawlers?

Tags: web-crawler, user-agent

I have a single page application where I use a headless browser to serve pages to web crawlers, giving them a version to the page that's very close to what actual users will see.

Currently, I'm *whitelisting* crawler user agents to a few: google, facebook, bing, yahoo, and linkedin.

I'm now looking to expand this into **something more robust** that targets each user agent, rather than just these. The reason for this is because if I *don't accept a particular crawler*, all they'll see will be *mustache HTML templates*. which is no good for me.

Is using a gigantic user agent regex the best approach? This is something that's going to be done for every request, so I need something that's fast, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of user agents: http://www.user-agents.org/ (found here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3264/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-search-engine-crawler-user-agents-and-their-domain-na)

If it is too much, you could implement a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) (a memory-efficient solution to perform 'if exist' tests).

About whitelisting and good practices, this may also interest you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37231/why-does-the-stack-overflow-sitemap-xml-use-a-user-agent-whitelist-instead-of-a